# Can't contact my mysql from another server

Tags: mysql

Can't contact my mysql from a another server
i've installed Mysql and changed the bind-adress from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

afterwards i've restarted the service

the firewall is open on port 3306, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the exact commands you used and their output or some log files?

Comment: i've used the following commands:

`apt-get install mysql-server -y`

`sudo mysql_secure_installation -y`

`vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

**Changed bind-address            = 127.0.0.1  -> bind-address            = 0.0.0.0**

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

+ i've opened the firewall with ufw allow 3306

Comment: OK, my question was related to the offending comands, the ones leading you to the conclusion you can't contact mysql.

Comment: this is what the error log wrote: https://imgur.com/a/uXvUA

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste those lines in the question?  This is the preferred way on this site.

Comment: Apart from this, I see two problems in the log: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` and `address xyz could not be resolved`.  So, 1; Allow the user 'root' to connect from localhost.  2. Double check the the IP adress comes from.

Answer (score 0):

by this `mysql_secure_installation -y` you remove access to root from another IP.

check that your user has permission to connect from any host
from localhost check this

`select User,Host from mysql.user;`

your user on the server must have `%` or `Ip address` of the server that wants to connect to mysql server.

based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html you can create a user with access from anywhere.

mysql> CREATE USER 'finley'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Answer (score 0):

You can grant permission  for another IP on with command Mysql> :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'another_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' with grant option;

flush privileges;
```

I think you can reconnect from another IP. But before reconnect you can check on another IP connect to 3306 of IP server DB Mysql: `telnet IP_Server_Mysql 3306`. If that's OK --> You can reconnect is OK